# Mazda 3 fan motor

Tags: troubleshooting, mazda, mazda-3, fan

fixing a wrecked Mazda 3 I checked the fan motor by straight wiring and fan runs backward. Is this normal when straight wiring it or is the fan bad ?

Comment: What fan? Radiator? Interior?  It's unlikely a "bad" fan would actually operate backwards.

Comment: DC motors on cars will run either direction depending on polarity of connections.